# JOIN syntax in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was tasked to create a new report on a legacy program. I needed to LEFT JOIN a table but I am getting Syntax error on JOIN Operation.

My SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT
 SUM(b.qty) as qty,
 b.price,
 c.item_desc,
 a.cust_name,
 e.curr_symbol
FROM (
tran_hdr a,
 tran_dtl b,
 items c ,
 tailoring e
(
LEFT JOIN 
 customers d
ON a.cust_name = d.name
)
)
WHERE a.tran_id = b.tran_id 
 AND b.item_no = c.item_no
GROUP BY  b.price,
   c.item_desc,
   a.cust_name,
   e.curr_symbol
```

I am joining the tran_hdr to customers. Because not all customers in Tran Header is maintained in customer table, but report requirest to show all Data in Transaction table.

Comment: How is tailoring table related to other tables? What table is it related and what field?

Comment: Nothing, no relation, tailoring is a setup table that has fixed 1 row. It has information like what currency to show in the report

Answer (score 0):

You're messing up your `JOINs`.
And your `Tailoring` table has no relation whatsoever to other table.

So, just try this one out:

```
SELECT
  b.price,
  c.item_desc,
  a.cust_name,
  e.curr_symbol,
  SUM(b.qty) as qty
FROM 
 tran_hdr a
 INNER JOIN tran_dtl b
  ON a.tran_id = b.tran_id 
 INNER JOIN items c 
  ON b.item_no = c.item_no
 LEFT JOIN 
  customers d
  ON a.cust_name = d.name
 ,tailoring e
 GROUP BY  b.price,
  c.item_desc,
  a.cust_name,
  e.curr_symbol
```

Comment: Its not working, this select is for MS Access not SQL Server.